# Bitwise operations (shifting return values)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

`if (((number >> i) & 1) == 1)`

this is my code example.

How is the return value determined in this operation? We shift numbers to the right or left. what is the return value?

`if (((number >> i) & 1) == 1)`

Comment: (number >> i) will shifter number i times to the right. Then "& 1" will AND that with 1, which will be either 1 or 0. And lastly we check if it actually was a 1. So the whole if statement checks if bit i is set in number.

Comment: See [Bitwise logic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic), [Shift operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Shift_operators) and [Equality operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison#Equality_operators). In general: [Expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number >> i` bitwise-shifts `number` to the right by `i` bits:

```
  number   i    number >> i
  ------   -    -----------
01010101   1    00101010
01010101   2    00010101
01010101   3    00001010
```

etc.

`(number >> i) & 1` does a bitwise-AND of `number >> 1` against `1`:

```
  00101010 (01010101 >> 1)
& 00000001
----------
  00000000

  00010101 (01010101 >> 2)
& 00000001
----------
  00000001
```

So basically,

```
if (((number >> i) & 1) == 1)
```

will branch if the low bit of the shifted value is set.

Answer (score 0):

> How is the return value determined in this operation?

There is no return value. There is an if statement with the equality operator

```
if (((number >> i) & 1) == 1)
```

The result of the equality operator is value `0` or `1` of the type `int` dependent on whether two operands, `((number >> i) & 1)` and `1`,  of the expression are unequal or equal to each other correspondingly. If the result is `1` (operands are equal each other) then the sub-statement of the if statement will get the control.

So the of statements checks whether the `i-th` bit of `number` is set to 1 or to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is a right-shift operator in C language.

It depends on three factors that the result of `((number >> i) & 1)` would be.

1. The type of the `number` is either signed or unsigned.
2. The total size in bit of the `number`, i.e. 8*sizeof(number).
3. The value of `i`.

|  | `number` is signed | `number` is unsigned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **The value of `i` >= The total size in bit of the `number`** | the signed bit of `number` | 0 |
| **The value of `i` < The total size in bit of the `number`** | the `i`-th bit of `number` (LSb is 0-th bit) | the `i`-th bit of `number` (LSb is 0-th bit) |

Comment: Shifting signed integers right is implementation-defined.  Not all implementations shift in copies of the sign bit.